# Draw Shapes on random places in C#

Tags: c#

I want to draw four shapes(rectangle, square, triangle, circle) on a panel in C# user control paint method. I have tried below code but it will draw shapes at same location(x,y). I declared four random variables but it did not work. I need to draw those shapes separately different locations. Is there anyone can help me?

Here is my code:

```
int recX;
int recY;
int squX;
int squY;
int circleX;
int circleY;
int triX;
int triY;
public int shapeType { get; set; }


public GameArea()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    food = new Food(randFood);
    Random randRectangle = new Random();
    recX = randRectangle.Next(1, 35) * 10;
    recY = randRectangle.Next(1, 35) * 10;

    Random randSquare = new Random();
    squX = randSquare.Next(1, 35) * 10;
    squY = randSquare.Next(1, 35) * 10;

    Random randCircle = new Random();
    circleX = randCircle.Next(1, 35) * 10;
    circleY = randCircle.Next(1, 35) * 10;

    Random randTriangle = new Random();
    triX = randTriangle.Next(1, 35) * 10;
    triY = randTriangle.Next(1, 35) * 10;
}
private void GameArea_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    paper = e.Graphics;
    if (shapeType != 0)
     {

        if(shapeType == Convert.ToInt32(Enums.ShapeTypes.Rectangle))
        {
            food.drawFood(paper, shapeType, recX,recY);
            food.drawSquare(paper, squX, squY);
            food.drawCircle(paper, circleX, circleY);

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same random over and over otherwise you'll be using the same seed.

Example:

```
Random rndLocGen = new Random();
recX = rndLocGen.Next(1, 35) * 10;
recY = rndLocGen.Next(1, 35) * 10;
cirX = rndLocGen.Next(1, 35) * 10;
cirY = rndLocGen.Next(1, 35) * 10;
```

Comment: Thank #TimHinz It really worked. Previously I tried it in the paint method of  user control but it always genarates random shapes because paint method is always firing. Thnkz a lot.

Comment: Even this may be too close; not here but in general. Moving the Random to class level is safer..

Comment: #TaW I got the problem but how to resolve it give me an example?

Comment: Glad I could help :)

As for as moving it to class level, he means take it out of the paint scope and put it in the global scope so the seeds not being recreated everytime.